# How to rebuild the build method

Tags: flutter

Click the button in appbar it trigger the show method in Controller class.
In that notifyPropertyChangedListeners is trigger the handleControllerValueChange changed the Boolean value as true inside the setstate but it didn't trigger the build method. how to trigger the build method. Thanks in Advance

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

typedef Listener = void Function({String property});

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool value = false;
  Controller controller = Controller();
  @override
  void initState() {
    controller?.addListener(handleControllerValueChange);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.removeListener(handleControllerValueChange);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: [
          FlatButton(
            color: Colors.pink,
            onPressed: () {
              controller.show();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text(value.toString()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void handleControllerValueChange({String property}) {
    if (property == 'show') {
      setState(() {
        value = true;
      });

      value = false;
    }
  }
}

class Controller extends ValueChangeNotifier {
  void show() {
    notifyPropertyChangedListeners(property: 'show');
  }
}

class ValueChangeNotifier {
  Listener listener;
  final ObserverList<Listener> _listeners = ObserverList<Listener>();

  void addListener(Listener listener) {
    _listeners.add(listener);
  }

  void removeListener(Listener listener) {
    _listeners.remove(listener);
  }

  @protected
  void notifyPropertyChangedListeners({String property}) {
    for (listener in _listeners) {
      listener(property: property);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think build works but we can not see that. you are calling setState and after that changing value to false.

Can you check that part of your code?

```
 if (property == 'show') {
      setState(() {
        value = true;
      });

      value = false; // delete here and test again.
    }
```

Comment: I want to rebuild the build method for two times when the value set as true for first time and set as false for second time because I need to update the text widget in build method .